# Flask HTML template w/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7, flask

I'm learning flask and trying to build a page that displays data of the fortune 500 companies in a table.

I've gotten that to display correctly and am now trying to be able to sort the table by any of the columns. It looks like I need some Javascript which I've stored in my static directory but I'm not quite clear on how to pull the javascript in.

Questions:

- Do I have the correct framework?
- How do I leverage javascript correctly?
- I had read that I should put any script tags in the head which is in base.html, is there ever a time I wouldn't do that?
- What questions am I not asking that I should be?

Below is my file structure

```
-app
 --static
   *sorttable.js
 --templates
   *base.html
   *companies.html
 --run.py
 --views.py
 --companies.csv
```

Below is base.html

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script> src="{{ url_for('static', filename='sorttable.js', type='text/javascript') }}"</script>
    {% if title %}
    <title>{{ title }} - microblog</title>
    {% else %}
    <title>Welcome to microblog</title>
    {% endif %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Microblog: <a href="/index">Home</a></div>
    <div>Login: <a href="/login">Here</a></div>
    <hr />
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is companies.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<table class="sortable">

<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Revenues </th>
            <th> Profits </th>
            <th> Rank </th>
            <th> Company </th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
    {% for keys in companies %}

       <tr>
            <td> {{ keys.Revenues }} </td>
            <td> {{ keys.Profits }} </td>
            <td> {{ keys.Rank }} </td>
            <td> {{ keys.Standard }} </td>
       </tr>

    {% endfor %}
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>

</table>
{% endblock %}
```

And run.py

```
# encoding: utf-8

from flask import render_template
from app import app
from .forms import LoginForm

@app.route('/companies')
def companies():
    import csv

    with open('companies.csv','rU') as f:
        companies = csv.DictReader(f)


        return render_template("companies.html",
                            title='Home',
                            companies=companies)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to how to get the lists to sort

I changed the line in base.html from:

```
<script> src="{{ url_for('static', filename='sorttable.js', type='text/javascript') }}"</script>
```

to

```
<script src="{{ config.STATIC_URL }}/static/sorttable.js"></script>
```

that seemed to do the trick.

I'd definitely love to get feedback from others on how this could be improved generally

Answer (score 0):

Your `script` tag is incorrect. Instead of closing the tag right after `script` (`<script>`), you need to include its attributes first.

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='sorttable.js') }}"></script>
```

`type="text/javascript"` is optional if you are using HTML5 (`<!doctype html>`) but should be included otherwise.